# Transaction receipt data size max length

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5, transactions

Before beginning to test the iOS autorenewing purchases I need to prepare my server database.  I just want to know what size I should make the varchar field in my database. I am using oracle db

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen it's something in excess of 2Kb.

I suggest you put it in a blob and stop worrying about it.